# TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly Error while running python script

Tags: python

When trying to run a python script for website scanning the error TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly keeps occuring the python code is

main.py

```
from general import *
from domain_name import *
from ip_address import *
from robots_txt import *
from whois import *
from nmap import *


ROOT_DIR = 'Targets'
create_dir(ROOT_DIR)

def gather_info(name, url):
    domain_name = get_domain_name(url)
    ip_address = get_ip_address(url)
    robots_txt = get_robots_txt(url)
    whois = get_whois(domain_name)
    nmap = get_nmap(input('Nmap Options:'), ip_address)
    create_report(name, url, domain_name, robots_txt, whois, nmap)

def create_report(name, full_url, domain_name, robots_txt, whois, nmap):
    project_dir = ROOT_DIR + '/' + name
    create_dir(project_dir)
    write_file(project_dir + '/full_url.txt', full_url)
    write_file(project_dir + '/domain_name.txt', domain_name)
    write_file(project_dir + '/robots_txt.txt', robots_txt)
    write_file(project_dir + '/whois.txt', whois)
    write_file(project_dir + '/nmap.txt', nmap)



gather_info(input('Target Name:'), input('Target Domain:'))
```

nmap.py

```
import os 

def get_nmap(options, ip):
    command = "nmap " + options + " " + ip
    process = os.popen(command)
    results = str(process.read())
    return results
```

When I run it it rrturns

```
python ./main.py 
Target Name:test
Target Domain:https://www.google.ie
Nmap Options:-F
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 31, in <module>
    gather_info(input('Target Name:'), input('Target Domain:'))
  File "./main.py", line 17, in gather_info
    nmap = get_nmap(input('Nmap Options:'), ip_address)
  File "/Projects/WebScanner/nmap.py", line 9, in get_nmap
    command = "nmap " + options + " " + ip
TypeError: Can't convert 'NoneType' object to str implicitly
```

I have searched through other similar errors but cannot find a solution to fix it any help would be great.

Comment: Well, it sounds like either `options` or `ip` is `None`. Without seeing `get_ip_address`, we can't really help.

Comment: I suspect it should be `get_ip_address(domain_name)`.

Comment: the get_ip_address.py is

Comment: import os


def get_ip_address(url):
    comamnd = 'dig +short ' + url
    process = os.popen(comamnd)
    results = str(process.read())
    return

Comment: I suspect your get IP is failing. Try 'print type(ip_address)' after your get and see what it says

Answer (score 0):

Python is telling you that it can't take an object of type `NoneType` and make it into a string for concatenation. Some where in your code your assigning either the `options` variable or the `ip` variable to None. Like Lost said above, print out `ip` and `options` and see if they print out `None`. Or you could say `command = "nmap " + str(options) + " " + str(ip)`, to see if your `ip` variable or `options` variable is `None`.